# Internal working of delegates in C#

Tags: c#, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How delegates work (in the background)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527489/how-delegates-work-in-the-background)

As we know delegate is function pointer.

How it is working internally?

Detailed explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a specific issue with a piece of code you're working on?

Comment: Why do you need to know this?

Answer (score 3):

The [following article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301810.aspx) presents a nice overview of delegates in .NET and how they work internally.

Comment: +1 - Damn, you found the article before me. Heh.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I'm sure someone will come up with a good literal explanation for this, I'd recommend reading the following book which covers everything nicely:

[http://www.amazon.com/dp/0735627045/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) (CLR via C#, Jeffrey Richter).

Comment: An answer that links to a reference number on amazon without even a mention of the book it refers to can only be considered a poor answer. Links go stale all the time.

Comment: You are linking to the 2nd edition, there's a third edition of "CLR via C#" at: http://www.amazon.com/CLR-via-C-Jeffrey-Richter/dp/0735627045/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Comment: Have updated link.  Thanks for the suggestions :-)

Comment: What, not Jon Skeet's book???

Comment: I've not read that one yet.  One day...

Answer (score 0):

> Delegates (1) in C# are lists of method pointers. I.e. they store
>   references to code, and you can invoke the methods via the pointers.
>   This is useful in many cases. The common example is for event handlers
>   where delegates are used to implement a publisher/subscriber pattern.

[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527489/how-delegates-work-in-the-background/527505#527505)