# What does a delegate point to?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I have read that a reference type holds the reference to an actual object which may be stored on the managed heap. When a method is "assigned" to a delegate reference variable, to what memory does the reference point to? What does this memory block has to do with the actual function code?

Comment: Not exactly the answer you are looking for but this post might provide some insight on delegates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527489/how-delegates-work-in-the-background

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's take apart a simple example:

```
using System;
class Program
{
    delegate bool MyFilter(int x);

    bool IsOdd(int x)
    {
        return x % 2 == 1;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MyFilter f = new Program().IsOdd;
        Console.WriteLine(f(5));
    }
}
```

What does the compiler do? Let's start with this line:

```
delegate bool MyFilter(int x);
```

The compiler generates a **type** that looks somewhat like this:

```
class MyFilter : MulticastDelegate
{
    public MyFilter(Object thisRef, IntPtr method);
    public bool Invoke(int x);
    // BeginInvoke(), EndInvoke() - Let's ignore those
}
```

The type MyFilter has a constructor that accepts two parameters: an IntPtr to the method body to invoke, and an Object on which this method should be invoked. The Invoke() method on the MyFilter type invokes the actual delegate.

Now, let's look at what happens in the Main() method. The compiler will rewrite it somewhat like this:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        MyFilter f = new MyFilter(new Program(), addressof(Program.IsOdd));
        Console.WriteLine(f.Invoke(5));
    }
```

Of course, addressof is not an actual C# operator, but you can imagine that it returns the address of the body for the method passed-in. Also, I didn't discuss various other topics related to delegates such as chaining (that's a feature provided by the MulticastDelegate base class), but hopefully I've addressed your question.

To summarize, the delegate reference points to an object that implements an Invoke method that matches the signature of the delegate. The object tracks the pointer to the method that needs to be invoked, and also the target object on which to invoke the method (unless the method is static).

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two delegate types, [Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx) and [MulticastDelegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx). These are abstract classes that are inherited from in an actual instance of a `delegate`. I would recommend reading up on those classes as they have much more (accurate) detail than I have explained here, but for the short version:

While I am not 100% certain how the implementation exactly works, the easiest way to think of a `Delegate` object is holding an `object`, and `MethodInfo`, which is the reflection type for a particular method. The reason the `Delegate` type is abstract, is because the `Invoke` method depends on the parameters of the method.

Similarly, `MulticastDelegate` hold multiple `Delegate` objects, which each point to an individual `object`/`MethodInfo` combination. This allows the `event` system, where a single `event` being fired results in multiple methods being called.

Going back to implementation details, when you define a delegate, it creates an inherited class from `MulticastDelegate` with an `Invoke` method, also the `object` can be `null` for static methods.

On top of this you have the specifics for how `MulticastDelegate` objects pass between invocations, but I have probably already made a few mistakes in this post, so I will leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

Without giving an over-complicated answer, it points (makes reference) to the actual memory block where the method is stored.

Answer (score 0):

A delegate actually contains two addresses - the address to the method as well as the address to the object. This is quite interesting, and several patents related to delegates were awarded to Heljsberg http://www.google.com/patents/US6185728

It is highly efficent. In an [interview](http://www.artima.com/intv/simplexity2.html), Heljsberg pointed out it can more efficient than VTBL dispatch (since it is a direct pointer to a function). In simplest cases it is literally an indirect call. e.g

```
 jmp *%eax
```

Overall, it takes [4 instructions to execute a delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507639.aspx).